# How to change more simple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, variables, args

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--model1', default='resnet18', type=str)
parser.add_argument('--model2', default='resnet34', type=str)
parser.add_argument('--model3', default='resnet50', type=str)
parser.add_argument('--model4', default='resnet101', type=str)
parser.add_argument('--model_count', default=4, type=int)

args = parser.parse_args()

model1 = create_model(args.model1)
model2 = create_model(args.model2)
model3 = create_model(args.model3)
model4 = create_model(args.model4)
```

I want to change above code using loop, how can I do?
I tried like below but it does not work.

```
for i in range(1, args.model_count+1):
    globals()["model{}".format(i)] = create_model(globals()["args.model{}".format(i)])
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  globals()["model{}".format(i)] = create_model(globals()["args.model{}".format(i)])
KeyError: 'args.model1'
```

Comment: Please clarify your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
args = [('--model1', 'resnet18'), ('--model2', 'resnet18'), 
    ('--model3', 'resnet50'), ('--model4', 'resnet101')]
for model, net in args:
    parser.add_argument(model, default=net, type=str)
parser.add_argument('--model_count', default=4, type=int)

args = parser.parse_args()

models_dict = {}
for i in range(1, 5):
    models_dict[f'model{i}'] = create_model(getattr(args, f'model{i}')
```

Comment: Glad to hear :), please accept the answer as "the answer"